# Calling function without event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to call the below function to execute on the below span, WITHOUT writing a script in the HTML.

I don't want to write a script in the HTML in order to follow the rule of separating behavior from mark-up.

And there is no listener event to trigger the function (the function simply generates a spam-proof email address without any triggering event).

How do I do this?

HTML:

```
<span id="myEmail"></span>
```

External JS file:

```
function myFunction() {
    /* a function to generate a spam-proof email address */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a function defined:

```
function myFunction() {
    // your code
}
```

You can call it by just invoking the name of the function anywhere in your code:

```
myFunction();
```

What does this function do?  Does it *return* the value?  Then you'd just capture and use that value:

```
var emailAddress = myFunction();
```

Do you then want to set it as the text of the `span`?

```
$('#myEmail').text(emailAddress);
```

Comment: Still not working. Can you take a look at this page: bit.ly/1DbbCFm. Focus on line 75 of HTML (<span id="emailGeneralAds"></span>) and lines 34-52 of /js/global.js.

Comment: @user4413288: I'd like to help, but I can't exactly debug your application for you.  Can you describe what "not working" means?  Maybe provide some updated information on what you tried?  Perhaps replicate the problem in a jsFiddle?

Comment: I replicated in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4f9b3cgz/.  It's not working.  The function is from jottings.com/obfuscator and is supposed to result in an email address in the span tag.

Comment: @user4413288: You forgot to include jQuery in the jsFiddle, the error console is saying that `$` is undefined.

Comment: are you able to see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7jpe7eba/.  I added jquery.  All that results is the email address.  The remainder of the HTML does not show in the result.  That's what happening on my site as well: bit.ly/1DbbCFm.  When I load my site, all that shows up is the email address and no other HTML (and Chrome is showing as loading).

Comment: further to above comment, new fiddle will not initialize so I don't know if you can see it.  But I can run the fiddle initially (without saving it), in order to see that the HTML does not show up.  Just load <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> and some HTML to a revised fiddle and you can replicate my result.

Comment: @user4413288: That fiddle isn't loading for me so I can't see what you're referring to, sorry.

Comment: It's not loading for me either but it does show when I run the fiddle.  Can you add <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> to top of HTML for this fiddle and run it, and you will see that only the email shows up:  http://jsfiddle.net/k5dupc5w/.  No other HTML shows up.  This is what's happening on my site as well.

Comment: @user4413288: In general, don't use `document.write()`. It doesn't give you a lot of control over where content is added to the document. I've updated here: http://jsfiddle.net/k5dupc5w/1/ The only change I've made is to use jQuery to identify the element and write the content to it instead of `document.write()`. It's not clear to me why you're using `$().text()` earlier with a `function` earlier in the code. `.text()` is just to write text.

Comment: it works now.  Thank you.  But do you think the obfuscation from http://jottings.com/obfuscator/ is still effective without document.write()?  The wizard at http://jottings.com/obfuscator/ produces that document.write() with or without the link text field completed in the wizard.  I'm just wondering if that document.write() is critical to the function's effectiveness in fighting spam?

Comment: also, I used    $().text() because the other person that submitted an answer used it.  What else would you recommend to apply a function to a span?

Comment: @user4413288: Well, you don't "apply a function to a span."  That doesn't really mean anything.  You can modify a span in various ways, and the code which does that can be inside a function that gets invoked somewhere.  But a span itself isn't functionality, it's just content.  A click event is functionality, for example.

Comment: so what would you recommend me applying the function to?  I need the function to apply to something to generate the email address in HTML.

Comment: @user4413288: I'm not sure how to explain this better, really. You don't "apply a function to a span." That literally makes no sense. The code *within* your function does some calculations and the last line sets the content of a span. That's all you need to do. That code can be run anywhere you like. What you would "apply a function" to is something like a click event or a mouse move event, or maybe an async callback.

Comment: separately, do you think the obfuscation from jottings.com/obfuscator is still effective without document.write()? The wizard at jottings.com/obfuscator produces that document.write() with or without the link text field completed in the wizard. I'm just wondering if that document.write() is critical to the function's effectiveness in fighting spam?

Comment: @user4413288: I can't really speak to how that particular library works.  But if it's relying on `document.write()` then it might not be a great choice of tools.

Answer (score 1):

In the external file, get  a reference to the DOM element of the `<span>`. Then, you can insert the result of `myFunction` into that element's text. Using jQuery:

```
$('#myEmail').text(myFunction());
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aoto0qor/).

Comment: I'm using http://www.jottings.com/obfuscator/ to generate the function to insert into the span element.  Your technique did not work when I put it into an external JS file.  But it did work when the .text script was in the HTML -- right below the span.  Any advice?

Comment: The code is being run before the page has loaded. Wrap the whole thing in `$(function () { ... })` to fix it.

Comment: Still not working. Can you take a look at this page: http://bit.ly/1DbbCFm. Focus on line 75 of HTML (<span id="emailGeneralAds"></span>) and lines 34-52 of /js/global.js.